# Solving Inequalities: Run time too long

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I am trying to solve the following system for d:

```
1/(3 + d) < 
 1/(6 (1 + d)) E^(-3 (1 + d) t) (1 + 3 d + 2 E^(3 (1 + d) t) - 
    E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) - 3 d E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) + 
    6 E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) (1 + 3 d + E^(2 d t) + 
        3 d E^(2 d t) + 2 E^(3 (1 + d) t))/(6 (1 + d) E^(2 d t)) + 
    6 d E^((-3 - d) t + 3 (1 + d) t) (1 + 3 d + E^(2 d t) + 
        3 d E^(2 d t) + 2 E^(3 (1 + d) t))/(6 (1 + d) E^(2 d t)))
```

So I tried Reduce[] on the expression. But the run time is way too long. It has been half an hour. I want to see what solutions exist for `0<d<1, 0<t`. How can I do this faster?

Comment: `Simplify[YourInequality,0<d<1&&0<t]` instantly returns `True` so that says every d,t in that domain is a solution to your inequality. `Table[d=RandomReal[{0,1}]; t=RandomReal[{-10,0}]; YourInequality,{1000}]` returns a list of 1000 `True`

Comment: Strange. When I try your approach it says running and never resolves.

Comment: But it works on the online version

Comment: Have you tried restarting Mathematica? Perhaps you have previously assigned something to d or t. Can you list the version numbers you are using? I used 12.0.0

Comment: Yep. That fixed it