# Finding a (sufficient) condition for an inequality - Solve takes too long

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, findinstance

I have the following inequality
$ 2 \sqrt{2} n^2 \sqrt{\frac{r}{r-1}} \exp \left(2^{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\log (n)}}{10 \sqrt[3]{\log (r)}}} \left(\frac{1}{r+1}\right)^{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\log
   (n)}}{10 \sqrt[3]{\log (r)}}}-\frac{(r-1) 2^{-\frac{1}{5} \sqrt[3]{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (r)}}-2} (r+1)^{\frac{1}{5} \sqrt[3]{\frac{\log (n)}{\log
   (r)}}}}{3 r+1}\right)\leq 1$

and want to find a function $n(r)$ such that the inequality holds by replacing $n$ by $n(r)$. Thus, I want to solve the inequality for $n$. $r$ is guaranteed to be greater than 1.

My first approach was

```
    Solve[2 Sqrt[2] E^(2^(-(Log[n]^(1/3)/(10 Log[r]^(1/3)))) (1/(1 + r))^(-(Log[n]^(1/3)/(10 Log[r]^(1/3)))) - (2^(-2 - 1/5 (Log[n]/Log[r])^(1/3)) (-1 + r) (1 + r)^(1/5 (Log[n]/Log[r])^(1/3)))/(1 + 3 r)) n^2 Sqrt[r/(-1 + r)] <= 1, n, Assumptions -> r > 1]
```

However, that has terminated in the long time I have been waiting. I tried
`Reduce[%]` (% is the given inequality), but doesn't terminate either.

I would also be happy for some other function $n(r)$ that is sufficient for the inequality to hold true, but not necessarily the border case. To that end, I tried `FindInstance[%,n]`, but that just returns the command (I might not be using it correctly?). I am not interested in any pair of (n,r) that satisfies the inequality but really in a function $n(r)$ that satisfies the inequality, so `FindInstance` might actually be the wrong approach.

Does anyone have ideas how to solve the inequality for $n$ or how to get a $n(r)$ that is sufficient for the inequality to hold?

I also considered [this post on solve being too long](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202603/solving-inequalities-run-time-too-long), but the suggested solution in the comments (restarting mathematica) did not help. It really seems to be the system itself that takes so much time.

**Edit** I had a small typo in the one constant, I have now updated the formula and code above. The limit of the LHS of the inequality is, as $n$ tends towards infinity indeed $0$, as one can check by:

```
Limit[2 Sqrt[
   2] E^(2^(-(Log[n]^(1/3)/(10 Log[r]^(1/3)))) (1/(1 + 
           r))^(-(Log[n]^(1/3)/(10 Log[r]^(1/3)))) - (2^(-2 - 
           1/5 (Log[n]/Log[r])^(1/3)) (-1 + 
          r) (1 + r)^(1/5 (Log[n]/Log[r])^(1/3)))/(1 + 3 r)) n^2 Sqrt[
   r/(-1 + r)], n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> r > 1]
```

Comment: Have you tried ContourPlot to at least see how the function n(r) looks like? The shape might also give you an intuition on the functional form or at least an approximation.

Comment: Use `CubeRoot` to obtain the real cube root of a real number.  At least then you will be able to use `Plot3D` and `ContourPlot` to get an idea of what you are dealing with.

Comment: It looks like the minimal value of this expression is about 7.07373 at n->1, r->6.78567*10^15. Therefore there is no solution for this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comments -- you are right, @AlexTrounev, I had a small typo (I'm very sorry!) that changed a lot. I have now updated the post and added a small code sample that illustrates that, now, the limit of the LHS is indeed 0 as n goes towards infinity, so in particular $\leq 1$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Two of the $5$ changed to $10$ -- should be in both the tex typesetted formula and the expressions (the difference is really subtle, but it changes the limit)

Comment: But it has same minimum  7.07373, at `{n -> 1., r -> 6.94387*10^14}`

Comment: Strange. So you say it is a global minimum? Do you also get that the limit, as n->infinity is 0? (from my code at the end of the question)

Comment: If you are looking for solution at $n\rightarrow \infty$ then it could be an answer. But for limited `n` there is one minimum 7.07373.

Comment: Yes. And I want to find how large $n$ has to be in terms of $r$ so that the inequality holds. Since this is a continuous function under the given conditions, and since the limit is 0, there must be some value of $n$ depending on $r$, so that it is at most $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take Log of function and Log[10,variable] to have a chance to handle it and show a graphic of solution. Also restrict n>1 for real values of Log[n].

```
f1 = 2 Sqrt[
    2] E^(2^(-(Log[n]^(1/3)/(10 Log[r]^(1/3)))) (1/(1 + 
            r))^(-(Log[n]^(1/3)/(10 Log[r]^(1/3)))) - (2^(-2 - 
            1/5 (Log[n]/Log[r])^(1/3)) (-1 + 
           r) (1 + r)^(1/5 (Log[n]/Log[r])^(1/3)))/(1 + 
         3 r)) n^2 Sqrt[r/(-1 + r)] // 
  FullSimplify[#, r > 1 && n > 1] &

f2 = Log[f1] // PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> r > 1 && n > 1] &

sol1 = First@
   Solve[rr == Log[10, r]^(1/3) && r > 1 && nn == Log[10, n]^(1/3) && 
     n > 1, {r, n}, Reals] // FullSimplify

(*   {r -> ConditionalExpression[10^rr^3, nn > 0 && rr > 0], 
     n -> ConditionalExpression[10^nn^3, nn > 0 && rr > 0]}   *)

f3[rr_, nn_] = 
 f2 /. {n -> 10^nn^3, r -> 10^rr^3} // 
   PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> rr > 0 && nn > 0] & // 
  FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> rr > 0 && nn > 0] &

(*   1/4 (2^(2 - nn/(10 rr)) (1 + 10^rr^3)^(nn/(10 rr)) - (
   2^(-(nn/(5 rr))) (-1 + 10^rr^3) (1 + 10^rr^3)^(nn/(5 rr)))/(
   1 + 3 10^rr^3) + 8 nn^3 Log[10] + Log[64] + rr^3 Log[100] - 
   2 Log[-1 + 10^rr^3])   *)

(cp = ContourPlot[f3[rr, nn], {rr, 0, 12}, {nn, 0, 12}, 
    Contours -> {10, 0, -10^3, -10^6, -10^9, -10^12, -10^15}, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 50, FrameLabel -> {rr, nn}, 
    ImageSize -> 400];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

Since function f1 has to be <= 1 , Log of f1 (=f3) has to be <= 0. Get corresponding r and n from sol1: r = 10^(rr^3)

**Edit**

Generate interpolating function for nn[rr], where f1 == 1, (f3 ==0), regarding nn as a function of rr and differentiating f3. Calculate intial value.

```
df3 = D[f3[rr, nn[rr]], rr];

nn4 = nn /. First@FindRoot[f3[4, nn] == 0, {nn, 1}]

nnsol = nn /. 
  First@NDSolve[{Numerator[Together[df3]] == 0, nn[4] == nn4}, 
    nn, {rr, 1, 12}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

pl = Plot[nnsol[rr], {rr, 1, 12}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[.3], Thickness[.02]}, PlotRange -> All];

Show[cp, pl]
```

[image]